# Django/Python unorderable types: complex() < complex()

Tags: python, django

'm learning Django and Python from tutorial, and most of the time there are bugs between different version of Django or Python.

I ran into this problem "unorderable types: complex() < complex()" because of this :

```
def top_stories(top=180, consider=1000):
    latest_stories = Story.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:consider]
    ranked_stories = sorted([(score(story), story) for story in latest_stories], reverse=True)
    return [story for score, story in ranked_stories][:top]
```

I found a solution that said: Use a key function to give stores a score:
    ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=score, reverse=True)
    return ranked_stories[:top]

But, this also wasn't working because of older version, so someone told me to try

"Yes, it has changed a bit. Now you have to specify a lambda for your sorting because key has to be something that is callable. Using lambda makes it callable on every item of the iterable object which you are using - ensuring that key can be used across any kind of object instances your own classes.

Try the following:

```
ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=lambda story: store.score(), reverse=True)
```

You may make it as complex as you want using the score object and that's the beauty of lambda"

This also didn't work.  It gave me a error saying "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'points'".

My model does have a points variable, I don't under stand why it's yelling at me.  Could someone see what's wrong with my code?

Here is the views.py code:

```
import datetime

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.utils.timezone import utc
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from stories.models import Story


def score(story, gravity=1.8, timebase=120):
    points = (story.points - 1)**0.8
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    age = int((now - story.created_at).total_seconds())/60
    return points/(age+timebase)**1.8

def top_stories(top=180, consider=1000):
    latest_stories = Story.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:consider]
    ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=lambda story:    latest_stories.points, reverse=True)
    return ranked_stories[:top]

def index(requet):
    stories = top_stories(top = 30)
    response ='''

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Tuts+  News</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>

        </ol>

    </body>
    </html>




    ''' % '\n'.join(['<li> %s </li>' % stories.title for story in stories])
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

And here is my models.py code:

```
from django.db import models
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    points = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User, default = '')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'stories'
```

Answer (score 0):

`latest_stories` is a `QuerySet`. You probably meant to use the lambda argument instead.

```
key=lambda story: story.points
```

Comment: Now it's yelling at me 'list' object has no attribute 'title'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'list' object has no attribute 'title'
Exception Location: /Users/vanle/Documents/Python/hackernews/stories/views.py in <listcomp>, line 41
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.3.

Comment: @Van change your code to `story.title for story in stories`

Comment: Nevermind, I changed to story.title which is what it's supposed to be.

Comment: But, it gave me this error not all arguments converted during string formatting
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
not all arguments converted during string formatting
Exception Location: /Users/vanle/Documents/Python/hackernews/stories/views.py in index, line 41